# What is a word meaning "the pros and cons of"?

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to find a word which can be used interchangeably with the phrase "pros and cons".

For example:

> Because no one has tried it yet, the *_* of this new diet are unknown.

The closest I can get is "characteristics", but to me, that seems not to carry the same good parts vs. bad parts meaning I'm trying to emphasize.

Comment: Has anyone considered "merits"??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the word **trade-offs** gives you the same meaning as pros and cons and also hints at the idea of good/bad.

> a balance achieved between two desirable but incompatible features; a
>   compromise.

Answer (score 2):

What about "effect". the effects of this diet are unknown.

Comment: That works grammatically with the example sentence, but is there a word which can apply not only to the results, but also to the intrinsic properties of the diet? "effects" might not cover something like the fact that the diet is a "rock only" diet, which _would_ be covered by "pros and cons".

Comment: What do you mean by"rock only"?

Comment: It was a pretty bad example, admittedly, but I meant a diet consisting only of rocks and stones, which would be a con intrinsically. (I guess it would also have bad effects.) I should have chosen something more believable like "rice only" or "candy only", which might also have intrinsic pros or cons.

Comment: I see, you are referring the overall effects of the diet, on your daily habits and the results on your health.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **[consequences](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/consequence)**

> A result or effect of an action or condition:

Answer (score 0):

***net benefit***

Meaning the benefit, but adjusted for any drawbacks.  Which may result in no benefit or harm.